# How do I clone 1 thing at a time instead of 1,2,4?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to clone a prefab once but I run into a problem where it duplicates by 2 each time

I have already tried different ways of instantiating the prefab and deleting the previous one so only one spawns. None have worked so this is my last resort. I know this is possible. I am looking for the same effect as this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xf6IM-KYbzs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawning_Projectiles : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject projectile;
    GameObject Clone;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            Clone = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            Destroy(Clone, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I only want the sequence to up by 1 E.G. 1,2,3,4
But in actual fact it duplicates : E.G. 1,2,4,8

Comment: What do you attach this script to? Maybe to the projectile you are trying to spawn?

Comment: If this script is attached to the thing you're cloning (the prefab), then each clone will also run this code.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I was late at night I am only just getting into programming in unity. This was a big help Thanks to all that helped

Answer (score -1, accepted):

set a bool so that it only clones once.

```
public class Spawning_Projectiles : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject projectile;
    GameObject Clone;
    bool hasCloned;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && !hasCloned)
        {
            Clone = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            hasCloned = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I had tried that earlier and it did not work for some strange reason. If you can would you explain how that spawn 1 not 2? Thanks for the help

Comment: each object will have this script living on it. the object is only allowed to clone if `hasCloned` is false when you click. after you click for the first time, `hasCloned` is set to true. and then it will fail the check to be allowed to clone next time you click.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the object you're instantiating doesn't have the `Spawning_Projectiles` script. The reason, why the number's doubling every time, is due to each new instance also making a copy when you try to instantiate your prefab.